# Read a particular word from a text file using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to read a text file using ajax and that is working fine, but I want to know that is there any way to read a particular word or sentence from a file using ajax.

Thank You

Comment: You can parse the file using JavaScript.  Or is your goal to avoid sending the entire file?  We  need a more specific question.

Comment: AJAX will get everything and anything the server gives it—always. That's just how HTTP works. You can get everything and then parse the data to get the content you want, or set it up so you can request from the server just the data you want.

Comment: Actually I want to extract an special word or phrase (that match a pattern) from the file and ignore other contents of the file.

Comment: Right, you have the parse the file.  Basically what Andrew and I are trying to ask you is: do you want to extract the phrase on the server side and only send the phrase to the web browser, or do you want to send the entire file to the web browser and extract the phrase on that end?  Note that the first method is not possible using only AJAX (you would need some kind of application, be it PHP, C, Perl or whatever on the other end).

Comment: Yes I want to go with the second option that is, i want to send the file to the client browser and then extract the word.
Also if you can tell me more about the server side extraction if the word using Java. Thanx

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting the particular word or sentence? E.g., do you want to select the ninth word, or the last word, or the first complete sentence containing the word "disputatious", or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn: I want to select the last word of each line

Answer (score 1):

OK, you want to get the last word from each line. Assuming you have retrieved the file via Ajax and have stuck it in a variable as a string:

```
var fileString = // whatever you did to retrieve it
```

Then you can use a regex to match the last word of each line, ignoring punctuation after the word (but remembering that words may contain apostrophes) and remembering that a line may have just one word in it, perhaps something like this:

```
var re = /(?:^| )([A-Za-z']+)(?:\W*)$/gm,
    matches = [],
    current;

while ((current = re.exec(fileString)) != null)
    matches.push(current[1]);

// matches array contains the last word of each line
```

Or you can split the string into lines and split each line on spaces to get the last word, then remove miscellaneous punctuation:

```
var lines = fileString.split("\n"),
    matches = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    matches.push(lines[i].split(" ").pop().replace(/[^A-Za-z']/g,""));

// matches array contains the last word of each line
```

Demo of both methods combined into a single jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qcpH/

Given that I've basically done all the work for you here I shall leave it to you to look up [how the regex works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and how [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) works.

With either solution you'll probably need to tweak it to handle extra punctuation and so forth exactly the way you want to.